# how to scale image and set background efficiently android

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, scale, android-relativelayout

I want to start a new project and i was wondering how to set the background for my activity (layout) very efficiently

Here is what i tried in the onCreate method :

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.perfectwall;
        int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        Bitmap reqBitmap = loadBitmap(imageUri, width, height);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), reqBitmap);
        r.setBackground(drawable);
```

also i have a question why this is not working... when i launch the app on the emulator it does not change the background although the memory is getting higher..up to 12MB used.. it is just a white screen like i didn't set the background

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Consider using libraries like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). They've been built precisely for what you want: to scale and load large images into imageviews efficiently. I've used both in the past and vouch for both of them.

Comment: and if i don't want just for imageviews? for example for screen layout or imagebutton

Comment: it gives me this error : `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Crunching Cruncher background.png failed, see logs`

Comment: @xyz so just use `r.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.perfectwall)`